# Data cardinality is ambiguous: Keras model prediction with multiple time series and vector inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have a model that takes in two inputs, one is a *sequence of vectors* and the other one is a simple *vector*, and my output is also a simple *vector*.
E.g. `x1.shape: (50000,50,2) x2.shape: (50000,2) y.shape: (50000,2)`

I have successfully trained and evaluated my model using `mode.fit` and `model.evaluate` with no errors as follows:

```
model.fit(
    x=[x1[:-validationLength], x2[:-validationLength]],
    y=y[:-validationLength],
    epochs=25,
    batch_size=256,
    validation_split=0.2,
)

model.evaluate(x=[x1[-validationLength:], x2[-validationLength:]],
    y=y[-validationLength:],
    batch_size=2)

2147/2147 [==============================] - 18s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0560 - accuracy: 0.8498
```

But when I try to use my model:

```
output = model.predict([x1[1000], x2[1000]])
```

the following error pops up:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 50, 2
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

IDK how this possible!!!!!

Here is a diagram of the model:
[image]

any suggestions will be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing the batch dimension and your first dimensions are being interpreted as the batch dimension, try:

```
output = model.predict([x1[None, 1000], x2[None, 1000]])
```